# Does glassfish 3.1.2 Open source edition contain all Java EE 6 components?

Tags: java-ee-6, glassfish-3

Does glassfish 3.1.2 Open source edition contain all Java EE 6 components? I'm trying to figure out my project dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the profile you choose.  Java EE 6 Web Profile or Full Platform.

A quick Google search will provide you with a comparison of features/components